# can't access json data even json.parse not working

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda

I have parsed a file using lambda-multipart-parser and got results like this
and my code is

```js
let result = await parser.parse(event);
let a= (result.files[0].content);
```

and o/p is

```json
 {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        65,
        99,
        99,
        111,
        117,
        110,
        116,
        110,
        117,
        109,
        98,
        101,
        114,
        44,
        85,
        115,
        101,
        114,
        110,
        97,
        109,
        101,
        44,
        80,
        97,
        115,
        115,
        119,
        111,
        114,
        100,
        44,
        76,
        99,
        111,
        110,
        97,
        109,
        101,
        44,
        83,
        116,
        97,
        116,
        117,
        115 ]}
```

so to get data if i give

```js
let a= (result.files[0].content.data);
```

I am getting output blank(i.e 1 in postman)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even thought `result.files[0].content` is written out as a plain object, it is actually a [`Buffer` object](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). So you'll have to use one of the methods on the object to retrieve the information, e.g., `result.files[0].content.toString('utf-8')` to get the UTF-8 string represented by the buffer.